# Endless API requests in react and nodejs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, request, mern

No matter the component I am in, I keep getting infinite requests. I saw these infinite requests in the chrome developer tool network section. This is how the request address looks like:

```
ws://localhost:3000/ws
```

The request name is `ws`.
The status code is: `101 Switching Protocol`. The application is a `MERN` stack application. I am using `axios` to handle the requets.
Here is an example of one of my API calls with axios:

```
//fetch user
useEffect(()=>{
  const ourRequest = axios.CancelToken.source() 

  const fetchSingleUser = async () =>{
    const response = await axios.get(`/users/singleUser/${path}`,{cancelToken: ourRequest.token})
    setUser(response.data);
  }

  fetchSingleUser()
  return () => {
    ourRequest.cancel()
  }
}, [])
```

What could be causing these requests?

Comment: It's a websocket request. It fires periodically to keep the connection alive.

Comment: Is that a problem to my application?

Comment: It was not happening previously and I can't tell what I did that triggered it

Comment: This code formatting and indentation is absolute chaos. Please try and keep things more orderly here so we can figure out what you're trying to do without having to guess.

Comment: If you see multiple messages being sent back & forth inside the same request, it's what I described. If there are multiple requests being sent, it's most likely a bug.

Comment: I noticed that as I turned off the network throttling, the websocket requests multiple requests stopped